# Configure JetBrains Toolbox to automatically update IDEs when new versions are released?

Tags: jetbrains-toolbox

I'd like them to update in the background without having to click on the toolbox and `Update all` every time there is a new release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's 'Update all tools automatically' option in Toolbox App settings (gear icon in top right of the screen.

You can also control this for each installed tool individually. This is controlled by the 'Install updates automatically' under the tools settings (use gear icon near tool name).